# How to get public dns name from aws ec2 describe-instances

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jq

I'm trying to make simple script which queries my ec2 instances and gets public dns name of instances which matches my filter. There is my first shot:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=tag:app,Values=swarm-cluster" \
              "Name=tag:role,Values=manager" \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName"
```

It almost works but I get something ugly:

```
[
    [
        ""
    ],
    [
        "ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.venus-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
    ]
]
```

I want just list of FQDNs, one per line. How to format output?
I know, I can do it with tr, sed and so on but I'd like use more sophisticated way. :)

Comment: Use the `jq` utility to parse JSON in shell scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just append `--output text` to your CLI call to get a text output.

Ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html

Comment: 5 votes in 12 days for a response to a question having 38 views and 0 votes?.. hum..

Answer (score 0):

By using jq you can parse the JSON response to get what you want.
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=tag:app,Values=swarm-cluster" \
              "Name=tag:role,Values=manager" \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName" | jq ".[0][1]"
```

That will give you:

```
"ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.venus-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for i in `cat kafka_instance_names`
do 
    aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$i" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName" | grep ec
done
```

```
  "ec2-54-166-168-168.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
  "ec2-52-72-30-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```